# JSON-over-HTTP LLD fails with name contains invalid character '{'

Tags: json, zabbix

I'm trying to configure a simple Host LLD from JSON over HTTP source, like this one: https://pastebin.com/raw/YWWxGs7y

It uses Preprocessing step with JSONpath (I can test it with built-in testing tool) and 3 LLD-macros which are JSONPaths, too. I test them with output (Result) JSON from built-in testing tool and https://jsonpath.com/

My LLD fails with multiple errors:

```
Cannot create host "{#LOCATION_ID}": name contains invalid character '{'.
Cannot create host "{#LOCATION_ID}": name contains invalid character '{'.
Cannot create host "{#LOCATION_ID}": name contains invalid character '{'.
Cannot create host "{#LOCATION_ID}": name contains invalid character '{'.​
...
```

I guess that LLD-Macro's value remains empty, but I have no idea how to check and solve this

My Template in Yaml https://pastebin.com/raw/bBHuJgEz

PS reposted from [zabbix forum](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/459526-json-over-http-lld-fails-with-name-contains-invalid-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct macro could be:

```
          lld_macro_paths:
            -
              lld_macro: '{#LOCATION_ID}'
              path: '$.id'
            -
              lld_macro: '{#LOCATION_NAME}'
              path: '$.name'
            -
              lld_macro: '{#LOCATION_TYPE}'
              path: '$.type'
```